# find all card numbers in which the largest id oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a request. It works but I can't upgrade it. I want it to show not all records from id cards, but only in which the largest id, that is can be that there are records from id cards, but at one id 100, and at another also record 101, I want that in the answer there was only record from 101.

```
select a.id,
       a.employee_id,
       a.STATUS,
       a.expiration_date,
       a.ID_CARD
  from EM_STATUS_CARD a
  left join EM_CARD b on  a.ID_CARD = b.ID_CARD
  where b.del != 'true' or  b.del is null
```

Comment: It's a bit tricky to understand your question It would be clearer if you provided sample input for the two tables and expected output derived from that input. Otherwise you're expecting people to guess what you want. Maybe you'll be lucky and somebody will guess correctly, but why not increase your chances of getting a timely and helpful answer?

Answer (score 0):

Its good practice to provide a sample data and expected result but in the absence of these information I believe you are looking for something like below query.

```
with main_query as (select a.id,
       a.employee_id,
       a.STATUS,
       a.expiration_date,
       a.ID_CARD
  from EM_STATUS_CARD a
  left join EM_CARD b on  a.ID_CARD = b.ID_CARD
  where b.del != 'true' or  b.del is null)
  select x.id, y.employee_id, y.id_card, y.status, y.expiration from
  (select max(id) id, id_card from main_query group by id_card) x, main_query y
  where a.id_card = b.id_card;
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work just fine. I did some refactoring, as Oracle supports `using` for join

```
select id,
       employee_id,
       STATUS,
       expiration_date,
       ID_CARD
from EM_STATUS_CARD
left join EM_CARD using(ID_CARD)
where (del != 'true' or del is null) and id = (
  select max(id) 
  from EM_STATUS_CARD
)
```